# Is linking R to a vowel in British English an intentional effort or a natural occurrence?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, rhoticity, sandhi

If I am not wrong, the linkage between words happens naturally when you try to pronounce the words quickly. Unlike American English, where the ending R is always clearly pronounced, British pronunciation has very specific rule that the ending R is only pronounced when it is followed by words starting with a vowel. **I wonder if this linkage in British English in particular is a conscious and intentional action that only happens after at least some processing in the brain.**

Also, take the words "grandpa" and "grandfather" as an example, they both end with a vowel in British English when pronounced alone. However, while I know British English speakers are fine when saying "Grand[pa] [is] sleeping" , **I wonder if they feel unnatural when saying "Grandfatha [is] sleeping", i.e. with completely silent R, instead of "Grandfatha "ris" sleeping"** (in a normal speaking pace and flat tone where the "is" is not specifically stressed).

Many thanks in advance for helping me on these 2 questions.

*Edit:
I apologize that this is not a good example as it has the option of contraction, i.e. "Grandpa's sleeping", which I think should be way more commonly used, but it is not the main point of this post, so please bear with me on this.*

Comment: They probably wouldn't say *Grandpa is sleeping*, but *Grandpa's sleeping*. A better example would be *Grandpa(r) asked me about my day.*

Comment: You just made me realized it's not a very good example, I should have used an example where contraction is not an option.

Comment: Recently I have bemoaned the loss of the silent R in British English as I hear it on my British programmes here in the US. I hear the hard R at the end of many words that used to be soft as you describe. I had never known it to be a rule to be observed but only thought it a delightful habit.

Comment: British people, whether with rhotic or with non-rhotic accents, pronounce "Grandfather is" with a linking r. Where usage varies is 1) whether the accent is rhotic or not; 2) among non-rhotic speakers, whether they insert an r-sound in "Grandpa is" and the like.

Comment: @RosieF - I agree, except to add that a _careful_  non-rhotic speaker would avoid sounding the 'r' in "Grandfather is", though most would include it in casual speech.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on both “Linking” and “Intrusive” R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R). It notes that **not** all *non*-rhotic accents possess the linking-R feature, and that some rhotic accents have an intrusive-R.

Comment: I think it's highly implausible that speakers are generally thinking of the rules/norms of their native language while engaged in the act.

Comment: I don't think anyone consciously chooses in everyday life which phonemes to use when saying a word.

Comment: This is why the first 20 years or so of American sociolinguistics was subsumed under discussions of statistical usage, software design, and transcription practice. This is harder stuff than rocket surgery.